# How can I save Material with a envMap property?

Tags: three.js

My Material has a `envMap`. I call `Material.toJSON()` to save it to `localStorage`.

There is an error reported ,saying

```
Texture.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'.
```

I debugged it, found the image is an array which is not the correct type.

Here is my question,how can I save my material with an `envMap` property correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[Update]: I've posted this as an issue which you can reference [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9458).

I just ran into this problem as well. I fixed it by modifying the THREE.js source as follows.

In the getDataURL function inside of toJSON, there is a section that assigns meta.images[ img ] paths to the data URLs of your envMap.

Here's my fix [starts at line 22134, rev 79]:

```js
if ( meta.images[ image.uuid ] === undefined ) {

    /* ADD THIS PART */
    if (image instanceof Array && image.length > 1) {

        meta.images[ image.uuid ] = {
            uuid: image.uuid,
            url: image.map((val) => { getDataURL(val) })
        };

    } else {

        meta.images[ image.uuid ] = {
            uuid: image.uuid,
            url: getDataURL( image )
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but when i try to load the exported model, it tries to load an image named ',,,,' so this hack may no be the right solution for this issue